# Group By on a calculated field using T-SQL

Tags: group-by, calculated-columns

I have the following code:

```
 select distinct m.property_id,
    m.property_size, 
    count(f.request_id) WOs, 
    round(cast(m.[property_size] as float(10)) / cast((f.[request_id] * 1000) as float(5)),2) as PER_1k_SQFT

from T1 m, T2 f
where m.property_id = f.property_id
and datepart(year,request_date) = '2015'
and datepart(month, f.request_date) = '12'
group by  m.property_id, m.property_size, round(cast(m.[property_size] as float(10)) / cast((f.[request_id] * 1000) as float(5)),2)
order by count(f.request_id) desc
```

My last column, PER_SQ_Ft is all zeros. Why isn't it populating the result of the calculation?

Comment: Why are you dividing by an id?

Comment: It's a property size, say, 15,987 divided by the # of work orders (times 1000). so ex: 15,987 sqft / 50 work orders.

Comment: I think i figured it out when I read your comment. My formula should read:
round(cast(m.[property_size] as float(10)) / cast((count(f.[request_id]) * 1000) as float(5)),2) as PER_1k_SQFT @martinsmith